# Create a dictionary from a list

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a dictionary in Python from this output:

```
["'a'=df2['a']", "'b'=df2['b']", "'c'=df2['c']", "'d'=df2['d']"]
```

I tried with this code:

```
list_columns = list(df2.columns)
list_dictionary = []
for row in list_columns:
    resultado = "'"+str(row)+"'" + "=" + "df2[" + "'" + row + "'" + "]"
    list_dictionary.append(resultado)
clean_list_dictionary = ','.join(list_dictionary).replace('"','')
dictionary = dict(clean_list_dictionary)
print(dictionary)
```

But I get an error:

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Do you have any idea how I can make this work?

Thank you in advance!

Output dictionary should look like this:

```
{
    'a' : df2['a'], 
    'b' : df2['b'], 
    'c' : df2['c'], 
    'd' : df2['d']
}
```

Comment: what do you expect the output to look like? also this is what your `clean_list_dictionary` looks like - `"''a'=df2['a']'=df2[''a'=df2['a']'],''b'=df2['b']'=df2[''b'=df2['b']'],''c'=df2['c']'=df2[''c'=df2['c']'],''d'=df2['d']'=df2[''d'=df2['d']']"
`

Comment: I would like to create a dictionary for with this format: 
'''
{'a' : df2['a'], 'b' : df2['b'], 'c' : df2['c'], 'd' : df2['d']}
'''
I will use it as global variables in an eval() function.

Comment: You can create a dict with the actual column (series) as value, but you cant have df2['a'] as part of variable in this form. it will either have to be a string such as `"df2['a']"` or the actual series that corresponds to this value

Comment: I have added 2 methods to do this in my answer - 1. convert the list of strings to a string that you can use `eval` on later. and 2. convert the list of strings directly to the final output of that `eval` in previous step, but using `eval` intermediately during iteration. Do let me know if those work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Method 1: Transforming your list of string for an `eval` later

As you have mentioned in your comment -

> I would like to create a dictionary for with this format: ''' {'a' : df2['a'], 'b' : df2['b'], 'c' : df2['c'], 'd' : df2['d']} ''' I will use it as global variables in an eval() function.

You can use the following to convert your input string

```
#dummy dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4]], columns=['a','b','c','d']) #Dummy dataframe

#your list of strings
l = ["'a'=df2['a']", "'b'=df2['b']", "'c'=df2['c']", "'d'=df2['d']"]

#Solution
def dict_string(l):
  s0 = [i.split('=') for i in l]
  s1 = '{' + ', '.join([': '.join([k,v]) for k,v in s0]) + '}'
  return s1


output = dict_string(l)
print(output)
eval(output)
```

```
#String before eval
{'a': df2['a'], 'b': df2['b'], 'c': df2['c'], 'd': df2['d']}   #<----

#String after eval
{'a': 0    1
 Name: a, dtype: int64, 
'b': 0    2
 Name: b, dtype: int64, 
'c': 0    3
 Name: c, dtype: int64, 
'd': 0    4
 Name: d, dtype: int64}
```

---

## Method 2: Using `eval` as part of your iteration of the list of strings

Here is a way to do this using list comprehensions and `eval`, as part of the iteration on the list of strings itself. This will give you the final output that you would get if you were to use `eval` on the dictionary string you are expecting.

```
#dummy dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4]], columns=['a','b','c','d']) #Dummy dataframe

#your list of strings
l = ["'a'=df2['a']", "'b'=df2['b']", "'c'=df2['c']", "'d'=df2['d']"]

#Solution
def eval_dict(l):
  s0 = [(eval(j) for j in i.split('=')) for i in l]
  s1 = {k:v for k,v in s0}
  return s1

output = eval_dict(l)
print(output)
```

```
{'a': 0    1
 Name: a, dtype: int64, 
'b': 0    2
 Name: b, dtype: int64, 
'c': 0    3
 Name: c, dtype: int64, 
'd': 0    4
 Name: d, dtype: int64}
```

The output is a dict that has 4 keys, `(a,b,c,d)` and 4 corresponding values for columns a, b, c, d from df2 respectively.

Comment: I used method 2. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the list,split by charater and  convert to dict.

Code:

```
dic= {}
[dic.update(dict( [l.split('=')])) for l in ls]
dic
```

Comment: This will output: [{"'a'": "df2['a']"},
 {"'b'": "df2['b']"},
 {"'c'": "df2['c']"},
 {"'d'": "df2['d']"}] its not what OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear what exactly you want to achieve.

1. If You have a pd.DataFrame() and you want to convert it to a dictionary where column names are keys and column values are dict values you should use [df.to_dict('series')](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html).

```
import pandas as pd

# Generate the dataframe
data = {'a': [1, 2, 1, 0], 'b': [2, 3, 4, 5], 'c': [10, 11, 12, 13], 'd': [21, 22, 23, 24]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

# Convert to dictionary
result = df.to_dict('series')

print(result)
```

2. If you have a list of strings that you need to convert to desired output than you should do it differently. What you have are strings 'df' while df in your dict is a variable. So you only need to extract the column names and use the variable df not the string 'df'

```
import pandas as pd

# Generate the dataframe
data = {'a': [1, 2, 1, 0], 'b': [2, 3, 4, 5], 'c': [10, 11, 12, 13], 'd': [21, 22, 23, 24]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

# create string list
lst = ["'a'=df2['a']", "'b'=df2['b']", "'c'=df2['c']", "'d'=df2['d']"]

# Convert to dictionary
result = {}
for item in lst:
  key = item[1]
  result[key] = df[key]

print(result)
```

The results are the same but in second case list of strings is created for no reason because first example can achieve the same results without it..

Answer (score 1):

I think this is exactly what you want.

```
data = ["'a'=df2['a']", "'b'=df2['b']", "'c'=df2['c']", "'d'=df2['d']"]
dic = {}
for d in data:
    k = d.split("=")[0]
    v = df2[d.split("=")[1].split("\'")[1]]
    dic.update({k: v})
print(dic)
```